# Pyserial: есть способ определить, идет ли прием в данный момент?

Tags: python, serial

Есть сеть поверх RS-485 с несколькими устройствами. Любое из устройств может начать передачу по собственной инициативе.

Ищу пути разрешения конфликтов и как один из вариантов: убеждаться, что никто не ведет передачу в данный момент, прежде чем передавать данные самому.

Со стороны передатчика это можно было бы сделать проверкой приемника: если в данный момент идет прием, значит линия занята.

На низкоуровневых языках и при наличии доступа к переферии это обычно доступно. Но не могу найти такой фичи в Pyserial.

Comment: ``ser.is_open``?

Comment: @Эникейщик, а это разве не открытие порта? По-моему как порт откроешь так она и будет отдавать True не зависимо от того, ведется прием данных в данный момент или нет. Или я не прав?

Comment: Да. Если порт открыт, то линия занята независимо от передачи данных. Так что перед передачей надо всегда проверять порт на открытие, а после передачи всегда закрывать, иначе другие не смогут передавать.

Comment: @Эникейщик, то, что вы пишете касается и RS485? Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что при открытии порта вся линия переходит в занятое состояние?

Comment: А, ой, не знаю. Я pyserial увидел и сразу на rs242 переключился. Тогда нужно проверить, как оно работает.

Comment: А `in_waiting` вам не подойдет? Атрибут содержит количество байт, которые ждут в буфере. Если там пусто, значит передачи нет.